# How to resolve error "'Cordova/CDVPlugin.h' file not found" (during Azure DevOps Xcode build step)?

Tags: xcode, azure, ionic-framework, azure-devops

Synopsis:

Automate deployment, of an Ionic app, to the Apple App Store.

Environments:

Dev machine (Macbook) running:

- Node 10.14.1
- Cordova 8.1.1
- Ionic 4.5.0
- Xcode 10.1

Azure DevOps Build Pipe steps:

1. npm install
2. ionic command
3. install apple certificate (disabled)
4. install apple provisioning profile (disabled)
5. xcode build  >> error here, now resolved -- see my answer below..
6. publish

yaml:

npm install

```
steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    verbose: false
```

ionic command

```
variables:
  IonicVersion: '4.5.0'
  CordovaVersion: '8.1.1'
steps:
- task: ms-vsclient.cordova-extension.ioniccommandtask.IonicCommand@1
  displayName: 'Ionic Command cordova build ios'
  inputs:
    ionicCommand: 'cordova build ios'
    ionicArgs: '--prod --release -- --buildFlag=\"-UseModernBuildSystem=0\"'
    ionicVersion: '$(IonicVersion)'
    cordovaVersion: '$(CordovaVersion)'
```

xcode build

```
variables:
  scheme: ''
steps:
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Xcode build'
  inputs:
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/MyApp.xcodeproj'
    scheme: '$(scheme)'
    xcodeVersion: 10
    destinationPlatformOption: iOS
    destinationSimulators: 'iPhone 6'
```

publish

```
    steps:
    - task: ms-vsclient.app-store.app-store-release.AppStoreRelease@1
    displayName: 'Publish to the App Store TestFlight track'
    inputs:
        serviceEndpoint: 'ACTRA Apple Dev Program'
        ipaPath: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.ipa'
```

What is working... I can build and deploy from my dev environment, with steps:

1. git clone my_app_repo
2. ionic cordova build ios --prod --release -- --buildFlag=\"-UseModernBuildSystem=0\"
3. open platforms/ios/MyApp.xcodeproj
4. set active scheme to Generic iOS Device
5. select Legacy Build System via File > Project Settings...
6. uncheck and re-check Automatically manage signing
7. select Apple dev Team (Provisioning Profile - from drop-down list)
8. build & deploy via Product > Archive > Distribute App

Issue/trouble:

During build step of Azure DevOps pipe, the following error occurs:

> > /Users/vsts/agent/2.144.0/work/1/s/platforms/ios/MyApp/Plugins/ionic-plugin-deeplinks/IonicDeeplinkPlugin.h:1:9: 'Cordova/CDVPlugin.h' file not found

I have dropped a powershell script after the ionic cmd step to check the folder contents, and the file CDVPlugin.h exists in the folder: /Users/vsts/agent/2.144.0/work/1/s/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public

> > Maybe the question is about resolving paths within the agent or xcode during build.  It seems xcode is unable to resolve path.

## Updates

Jan 10, 2019 - changed scheme from '' to 'MyApp' to resolve build issue, moving on to archive..

References:

1. [Build, test, and deploy Xcode apps in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xcode?view=vsts)
2. [Xcode task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=vsts)
3. [Xcode build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode-build?view=tfs-2018)

Answer (score 1):

My immediate issue of having a failed build was resolved by setting the scheme variable correctly to 'MyApp'.  I will continue to update this question (and my answer) while working to the end goal of having a working Azure DevOps build pipe that deploys MyApp to the Apple App Store into TestFlight.  Outstanding things are signing, archiving and deploying.

Final Xcode build (and archive) step yaml:

```
variables:
    configuration: 'Release'
    scheme: 'MyApp'
steps:
    - task: Xcode@5
displayName: 'Xcode build archive'
inputs:
    actions: 'build archive'
    configuration: '$(configuration)'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/MyApp.xcodeproj'
    scheme: '$(scheme)'
    xcodeVersion: 10
```